# jenkins ldap alternative port

Tags: jenkins, ldap

I am setting up Jenkins to authenticate against LDAP with the LDAP plugin. I finally got everything configured and users in allowed groups are authenticated.

I now would like to point Jenkins at a different port so that LDAP users go through a DUO two factor proxy instead of regular LDAP.

DUO is configured correctly and with other LDAP implementations pointed at the alternative port it works as expected. With Jenkins however, it seems like it is skipping the alternate port and going through regular LDAP ports.

Any help, pointers, strange logs you can point me at would be greatly appreciated!